# Replace ArrayAdapter's dataset

Tags: android, listview

In Android, you can provide an `ArrayList` when creating an `ArrayAdapter` for a `ListView`. I need to update a number of items in the `ArrayList`.

The ususal way is to just call `notifyDatasetChanged`. What I prefer to do is reload the entire data into a new `ArrayList` from my database and then apply this new `ArrayList` to the existing `ArrayAdapter` but without creating a new adapter. Creating a new adapter will cause the `ListView` to go blank and start with position zero. This would also be obvious if the user were scrolling and I suddenly recreated a new adapter.

Is it possible to apply a completely new `ArrayList` to the existing adapter? The primary reason I want to do this is because it is very fast to just reload a new `ArrayList` with all the data than having to go through an existing `ArrayList` and inserting, deleting or updating existing items.

Comment: AFAIK, `clear()`, `addAll()`, and `notifyDataSetChange()` (in that order) will be your only option, and I expect that it will have the exact same effect that you're trying to avoid ("This would also be obvious if the user were scrolling and I suddenly recreated a new adapter"). You are also welcome to create your own subclass of `BaseAdapter` that behaves differently, though since you're not in control over `ListView`, you cannot completely control what happens when you change the data.

Comment: I decided to copy the original source code for the ArrayAdapter and add a method that allows me to replace the data source. Not sure at the moment what effect this will have but seems to be a legitimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all. You need to use custom ArrayAdapter (or SimpleAdapter or        RecycleViewAdapter)

2) Than create function in your custom adapter :

```
 // Initialize your list;
 private ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
 .....
 //Create constructor and past starting ArrayList
 public MyAdapter (ArrayList<Model> array) {
     this.arrayList = array;
 }
 ......
 public void updateMyData (ArrayList array) {
    clear();
    // Or you can use arrayList.addAll(array); - just add new items
    this.arrayList = array;
    notifyDataSetChange();
 }
 .....
```

3) In your Activity (or where you initialize adapter) 
   just use code like this:

```
  MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(startArratListData);
 // And Than for updating data:
 myAdapter.updateMyData(newArrayListData);
```